# Firebase Storage : How to check image is exist or not in my Storage? (React JS)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

My function is working fine when an image exists, in my case when I triggered the delete function image might not exist.
when the image does not exist I am getting an error.
( DELETE https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/anayase-dc577.appspot.com/o/userimages%2Fcustomerimage%2Fa%20(2).jpg 404)

```
function DeleteImage(path, imgname) {
    const storage = getStorage();
    // Create a reference to the file to delete
    const imageRef = ref(storage, path + '/' + imgname);
    console.log(imageRef)
    // Delete the file

    deleteObject(imageRef).then(() => {
        console.log("File Deleted Successfully")
    }).catch((error) => {
     console.log(error)
    });

}
```

Comment: your catch block is not handling it?

Comment: no, I try with extra try-catch block

Comment: instead of logging the error you can keep it empty this will not log error and nothing will happen

Comment: this error logged without logging

( DELETE https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/anayase-dc577.appspot.com/o/userimages%2Fcustomerimage%2Fa%20(2).jpg 404)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple if else for this. Check if the imageRef is null, or whether it's having a null prop. Based on that, you can perform the delete operation.

for an example,

```
if(imageRef !== null){
 deleteObject(imageRef).then(() => {
        console.log("File Deleted Successfully")
    }).catch((error) => {
     console.log(error)
    });
}
```

or,

```
if(imageRef.prop !== null){
     deleteObject(imageRef).then(() => {
            console.log("File Deleted Successfully")
        }).catch((error) => {
         console.log(error)
        });
    }
```

note that prop is a property that is in the imageRef object.

Comment: Thank you for your effort but this solution is not working.
I think imageRef is a retuning object.

Comment: Could be. Try checking a prop inside the imageRef object. try modifying if(imageRef.prop !== null){}

Comment: imageRef.prop here what is prop? can you explain it, please?

Comment: prop can be any property that is in imageRef object

Comment: here are huge properties & I cannot identify the correct one.