# How to Query By Firebase Timestamp (from - to)?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i want to query my data by time stamp

```
let date = new Date();
var today = new Date();
var yesterday = date.setDate(today.getDate() - 1);
console.log(date)
const dataTable = collection(db, 'sales')
let mquery = query(dataTable, where('createdDate', "<", yesterday))
const qSnap = await getDocs(mquery)
console.log(qSnap)
```

error : Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Expected type 'mc', but it was: a custom xh object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error that you encountered was produced by not using the `query()` method as pointed out by @AyseAsude. Now, after fixing the query, you should also convert the variable `yesterday` into a `date` format and iterate the items from the query. See code below:

```
let date = new Date();
var today = new Date();
var yesterday = new Date(date.setDate(today.getDate() - 1));

const dataTable = collection(db, 'sales')
let mquery = query(dataTable, where('createdDate', "<", yesterday))
const qSnap = await getDocs(mquery)

qSnap.forEach((doc) => {
  // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

For more information, you check out this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query).

Comment: this is soo good to hear from you. I am thankful to you. thank you so so much.

Comment: please have a look on this question to

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73064340/firebase-storage-how-to-check-image-is-exist-or-not-in-my-storage-react-js

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `query` function and create `Query` instance.

```
import {query} from "firebase/firestore";

let mquery = query(dataTable, where('createdDate', "<", yesterday))
const qSnap = await getDocs(mquery)
```

Documentations to refer to:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#query

Comment: thank you but this is not working for me
this is my last code 

let date = new Date();
var today = new Date();
var yesterday = date.setDate(today.getDate() - 3);
console.log(yesterday)
const dataTable = collection(db, 'sales')
let mquery = query(dataTable, where('createdDate', ">", yesterday))
const qSnap = await getDocs(mquery)